# Filtering rows of a 2d array by a certain value

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, iteration

I am a beginner in Java. For my task I've been given such table. The table represents 6 runners who participated in 7 races. The value in each cell is the place they got in the particular race:

[image: The table]

The task of my program is to print the number of runners who finished 1st in at least one of the races. I managed to write a code that counts the number of 1st places achieved by all of the runners, however I am struggling to find a solution how to add those runners, who finished 1st multiple times, to the count only once. How do I iterate to the next row when a matching value has been found and added to the count? Here's my code so far:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int A[][] = {{21, 14, 1, 21, 19, 5, 2},
                {4, 27, 1, 7, 25, 19, 19},
                {12, 20, 25, 11, 30, 14, 15},
                {5, 8, 5, 7, 1, 2, 13},
                {20, 2, 14, 4, 25, 1, 1},
                {14, 20, 20, 15, 11, 18, 16}};

        int i, j;
        int counter = 0;

        System.out.println("result:");
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                if (A[i][j] == 1) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print(counter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep track of runner who already finished first in a race, you can have a Boolean array like the following

```java
boolean[] firstPlaceRunner = new boolean[A[0].length];
```

ith position of the above boolean array stores the following information:

1. True - if the ith runner secured 1st place in any of the races.
2. False - If the ith runner was not able to secure 1st place in any of the races.

So, now in your code, you can only increment the counter when the current runner hasn't secured 1st place yet. So your code looks like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] A = {{21, 14, 1, 21, 19, 5, 2},
            {4, 27, 1, 7, 25, 19, 19},
            {12, 20, 25, 11, 30, 14, 15},
            {5, 8, 5, 7, 1, 2, 13},
            {20, 2, 14, 4, 25, 1, 1},
            {14, 20, 20, 15, 11, 18, 16}};
    int counter = 0;
    // A[0].length gives the number of runner in any race
    boolean[] firstPlaceRunner = new boolean[A[0].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (A[i][j] == 1) {
                if (!firstPlaceRunner[j]) {
                    counter++;
                    // because now jth runner has secured first
                    // place, and in future we don't want to
                    firstPlaceRunner[j] = true;
                    // double count it
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("result:");
    System.out.print(counter);
}
```

Note: As an improvement to our algorithm you can put a `break` statement after the following line in the code since there can be only one 1st place winner:

```java
firstPlaceRunner[j] = true;
break;
```

So basically, you are saying that if we have found the first place runner for a given race, then don't check for other runners.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the [`range`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range(int,int)) of row indices of this matrix, and [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#filter(java.util.function.IntPredicate)) out those rows, that contain [`anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.IntPredicate)) of a `1`:

```java
int[][] runners = {
        {21, 14, 1, 21, 19, 5, 2},
        {4, 27, 1, 7, 25, 19, 19},
        {12, 20, 25, 11, 30, 14, 15},
        {5, 8, 5, 7, 1, 2, 13},
        {20, 2, 14, 4, 25, 1, 1},
        {14, 20, 20, 15, 11, 18, 16}};

int[] winners = IntStream
        // iterate over indices of
        // the rows of 2d array
        .range(0, runners.length)
        // filer rows where at least
        // one element matches '1'
        .filter(i -> Arrays.stream(runners[i])
                .anyMatch(j -> j == 1))
        // array of indices
        .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(winners)); // [0, 1, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a break in the if statement:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int A[][] = {{21, 14, 1, 21, 19, 5, 2},
                {4, 27, 1, 7, 25, 19, 19},
                {12, 20, 25, 11, 30, 14, 15},
                {5, 8, 5, 7, 1, 2, 13},
                {20, 2, 14, 4, 25, 1, 1},
                {14, 20, 20, 15, 11, 18, 16}};

        int i, j;
        int counter = 0;

        System.out.println("result:");
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                if (A[i][j] == 1) {
                    counter++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print(counter);
    }
}
```